# Xamarin.Forms - Join two Streams to single Stream

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, stream

I looking for a solution how to join two Streams to one single Stream. I have loaded an .mp3 file from resources to Stream and I want to add the loaded Stream to a Stream I have created before.

Is there a way how to do it in Xamarin.Forms in C#?

Thank you !!!

Comment: do you want to mix two different audio files together?  Or if not, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add an audio file converted to Stream on the end of the current audio Stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply join two audio files by joining their streams!

Try [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio#working-with-audio-files)

Note that you've to install its new (**preview**) [.net standard compatible version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/1.9.0-preview1).

I've used that in C# & ASP.NET, but give it a try in Xamarin app too.